# One, two, three, four

Tags: riddle, word

> I can fly: east, west, south or north
>   I can hear your confession: greed, pride, lust or sloth

Who am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are a

> Cardinal.

One, two, three, four

> These are *cardinal* numbers

I can fly

> A cardinal is a bird

east, west, south, or north

> These are the *cardinal* directions.

I can hear your confessions

> Cardinal is a position within the Catholic church that takes confessions and gives absolution.

greed, pride, lust, or sloth

> These are commonly referred to as *cardinal* sins.

Comment: First 3 words also refer to the rot13(oveq)...

Comment: I think I got all the references now.